# Python: How to get count of values based on datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have written the following code which creates two dataframes `nq` and `cmnt`.
`nq` contains the `UserId` and corresponding time of Badge Attainment `date`.
`cmnt` contains `OwnerUserId` and the time when the User made a comment `CreationDate`.
I want to get a count of the comments made for all days before and after 1 week of badge attainment so that I can create a time series line plot out of it.

The following code perform the same but produces a KeyError. Please provide a code that performs this operations for all users.

**nq**

```
 UserId |   date 
     1      2009-10-17 17:38:32.590
     2      2009-10-19 00:37:23.067
     3      2009-10-20 08:37:14.143
     4      2009-10-21 18:07:51.247
     5      2009-10-22 21:25:24.483
```

**cmnt**

```
OwnerUserId | CreationDate
1             2009-10-16 17:38:32.590
1             2009-10-18 17:38:32.590
2             2009-10-18 00:37:23.067
2             2009-10-17 00:37:23.067
2             2009-10-20 00:37:23.067
3             2009-10-19 08:37:14.143
4             2009-10-20 18:07:51.247
5             2009-10-21 21:25:24.483
```

**code**

```
 nq.date = pd.to_datetime(nq.date)
 cmnt.CreationDate = pd.to_datetime(cmnt.CreationDate)

 count= []
   
 for j in range(len(nq)): 
      for i in range(-7,8):
        
          check_date = nq.date.iloc[j] + timedelta(days=i)
          
          count = cmnt.loc[(cmnt.OwnerUserId == nq.UserId.iloc[j]) & (cmnt.CreationDate == check_date)].shape[0]
          nq.iloc[j].append({nq[i]:count})
```

**expected output**

```
UserId     |   date                 |-7|-6|-5|-4|-3|-2|-1|0 |1 |2 |3 |4 |5 |6 |7
     1      2009-10-17 17:38:32.590 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |1 |0 |1 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0  
     2      2009-10-19 00:37:23.067 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |1 |1 |0 |1 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0    
     3      2009-10-20 08:37:14.143 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |1 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 
     4      2009-10-21 18:07:51.247 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |1 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 
     5      2009-10-22 21:25:24.483 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |1 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0
```

Here column `-1` means comment made 1 day before badge attainment and `1` means comment made one day after badge attainment and so on.

**Note**
There can be a completely alternately way to do this. My main objective is to draw a time series line plot which shows the number of comments made by the users before and after attainment of the badge.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want a cross-merge, filter and then a `crosstab`:

```
# merge the two dataframes
merged = (nq.merge(cmnt, left_on='UserId', 
         right_on='OwnerUserId',
         how='left')
)

# extract the date difference between `date` and `CreationDate`
merged['date_diff'] = merged['date'].dt.normalize() - merged['CreationDate'].dt.normalize()
merged['date_diff'] = (merged['date_diff'] / pd.to_timedelta('1D')).astype(int)

# filter the comments within the range
merged = merged[merged['date_diff'].between(-7,7)]

# crosstab
pd.crosstab([merged['UserId'],merged['date']], merged['date_diff'])
```

Output:

```
date_diff                       -1   1   2
UserId date                               
1      2009-10-17 17:38:32.590   1   1   0
2      2009-10-19 00:37:23.067   1   1   1
3      2009-10-20 08:37:14.143   0   1   0
4      2009-10-21 18:07:51.247   0   1   0
5      2009-10-22 21:25:24.483   0   1   0
```

Comment: This gives the correct output. Can you please add to your solution how to convert this crosstab to a dataframe?

Comment: That crosstab command returns a dataframe. Just assign it to some thing, e.g. `out = pd.crosstab(...)`.

Comment: It is but I want it to have the following columns ['UserId', "date", -7, -6, ...0....,6, 7] which I can access like normal DataFrame columns. But now the columns are `Int64Index([-7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], dtype='int64', name='date_diff')`.   So now the command df['UserId'] gives error as 'UserId' is not a column of df. (df = pd.crosstab(...))

Comment: chain `reset_index()` with that `pd.crosstab()`.

Comment: Also for some inputs I get this error `ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer`. How to fix this?